# Nextjs app with node server deployment issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, next.js

My application is not running properly when i deploy it on next or heroku. All my pages renders correctly except for one of the pages where i'm not using getInitialProps to get my props. I am using useEffect since i need to make sure a token exist to compare it to the token created by my server when my user log in so the server can send the proper data requested. Everything works perfectly on localhost but when i deploy the application, the page in question doesnt work. Here is the code and any help will be appreciated.
next.config.js:

```html
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS();

Vercel Logs:
12:51:02.854  
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/opt-out-auto-static-optimization
12:51:03.018  
Page                                                           Size     First Load JS
12:51:03.019  
┌ λ /                                                          952 B          85.5 kB
12:51:03.019  
├   /_app                                                      1.94 kB        72.1 kB
12:51:03.019  
├ λ /404                                                       2.6 kB         74.7 kB
12:51:03.019  
├ λ /bookings/Bookings                                         883 B          85.5 kB
12:51:03.019  
├ λ /host                                                      1.03 kB        85.6 kB
12:51:03.019  
├ λ /host/[id]                                                 574 B          89.6 kB
12:51:03.019  
├ λ /host/new                                                  312 B          89.3 kB
12:51:03.019  
└ λ /houses/[id]                                               21.8 kB         106 kB
12:51:03.019  
+ First Load JS shared by all                                  72.1 kB
12:51:03.019  
  ├ static/pages/_app.js                                       1.94 kB
12:51:03.019  
  ├ chunks/cd51de3554d810d8c7ceaf1ee16efdf432e5aab4.838cae.js  11.6 kB
12:51:03.019  
  ├ chunks/commons.07e586.js                                   10.7 kB
12:51:03.019  
  ├ chunks/framework.c61f0e.js                                 40.8 kB
12:51:03.019  
  ├ chunks/styles.a0e702.js                                    93 B
12:51:03.019  
  ├ runtime/main.b6ad58.js                                     6.27 kB
12:51:03.019  
  ├ runtime/webpack.6ef28d.js                                  746 B
12:51:03.019  
  └ css/styles.2330443d.chunk.css                              3.13 kB
12:51:03.019  
λ  (Lambda)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
12:51:03.019  
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
12:51:03.019  
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
12:51:07.814  
Traced Next.js serverless functions for external files in: 4693.896ms
12:51:08.764  
Compressed shared serverless function files: 950.419ms
12:51:09.150  
All serverless functions created in: 385.553ms
12:51:09.350  
Uploading build outputs...
12:51:13.210  
Build completed. Populating build cache...
12:51:20.629  
Uploading build cache [14.26 MB]...
12:51:21.018  
Build cache uploaded: 389.705ms
12:51:21.031  
Done with "package.json"
```

Booking.js

```html
import Layout from "../../components/Layout";
import Head from "next/head";

import { useStoreActions, useStoreState } from "easy-peasy";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Bookings = (props) => {
  const setHouseBooked = useStoreActions(
    (actions) => actions.user.setHouseBooked
  );
  const setUser = useStoreActions((actions) => actions.user.setUser);
  const data = useStoreState((state) => state.user.houseBooked);

  const fetchingDataOnMount = () => {
    const token = window.sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      fetch("https://polar-refuge-69571.herokuapp.com/api/login", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          authorization: token,
        },
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          if (data && data.id) {
            fetch(
              `https://polar-refuge-69571.herokuapp.com/api/house/bookings/list/${data.id}`,
              {
                method: "get",
                headers: {
                  "content-type": "application/json",
                  authorization: token,
                },
              }
            )
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((res) => {
                setHouseBooked(res);
                setUser();
              });
          }
        });
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchingDataOnMount();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Layout
      content={
        <div>
          <Head>
            <title>Your bookings</title>
          </Head>
          <h2>Your bookings</h2>

          <div className="bookings">
            {data && data.bookings && data.bookings.length > 0 ? (
              data.bookings.map((booking, index) => {
                return (
                  <div className="booking" key={index}>
                    <img src={booking.house.picture} alt="House picture" />
                    <div>
                      <h2>
                        {booking.house.title} in {booking.house.town}
                      </h2>
                      <p>
                        Booked from{" "}
                        {new Date(booking.booking.startDate).toDateString()} to{" "}
                        {new Date(booking.booking.endDate).toDateString()}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })
            ) : (
              <div>no House booked</div>
            )}
          </div>

          <style jsx>{`
            .bookings {
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
              grid-gap: 40px;
            }
            .booking {
              display: grid;
              grid-template-columns: 100%;
              grid-gap: 40px;
              margin-top: 60px;
            }

            .booking img {
              width: 180px;
            }
          `}</style>
        </div>
      }
    />
  );
};

export default Bookings;
```

```
Files Setup
Components
Pages
 host
  [id].js
  index.js
  new.js
 houses
  [id].js
 _app.js
  Booking.js
  index.js
store.js
```

Comment: Did you see any error logs?

Comment: No error was logged in, just a 404 on the page requested when hosted. I have a feeling the main reason why I am getting this error is because I'm not using getInitialProps but useEffect(). I'm using useEffect because I need to compare the token received to the one created when the user logged in to authenticate the request. I don't get any error as well when hosted on heroku or vercel just on the page in the browser.

Comment: I see you are not catching error in both of your fetch methods. Maybe chain a `.catch` in the end will give you more insight?

Comment: I just did nothing is being logged in the console or in Heroku logs

Comment: If you see '404 This page could not be found.' instead of 'An unexpected error has occurred.', the problem is unlikely to be caused by `useEffect`. My guess is that the page is never built. (maybe the file is never committed? I'm not sure) You may check the build logs to see what pages were built. (they should be shown after the message 'Automatically optimizing pages')

Comment: I just went through the log and the build logs shows that a 404 then the page then all rhe other page here is the logs in question:

Comment: I added the logs above

Comment: I redeployed it by changing a few things but I am still getting the same problem the page in question shows a 200 but with error. I am not sure but can it be related to the way i set up my files because it seems as if it is not reading the page though it shows the page being built.

Comment: This is my setup:

Comment: So the build logs show there is a page on /bookings/Bookings but I didn’t see from your folder structure there is a bookings folder? If your repo is hosted on github or open source, I am happy to have a look.

Comment: Sure I changed the file structure by just keeping bookings.js and delete the folder bookings. It gave me the same outcome. here is the link of the repo https://github.com/morpheus86/clonebnb

Comment: Have you tried visiting both "https://yourdomain.com/bookings" and "https://yourdomain.com/Bookings"?

Comment: I did that thats where the error comes in

Comment: I see. I was confirming if it was due to letter casing.

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding the component Booking into the host folder. There were a few issues: One was related to the casing which you pointed out and the other was the url was not being redirected properly to the link. Thanks for taking the time and helping with this issue